# creating some new columns based on old ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Create a new column Age. This is the current year (2019) minus the car's Year. If Age is 0, set it to 1.

> Q1.Create a new column Age. This is the current year (2019) minus the
> car's Year. If Age is 0, set it to 1. My codes are below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('car_train_data.csv',sep= ";",index_col= 0)
#method1
df["age"]= df[['age']].applymap(lambda x: 1 if pd(x) = 0)
#method2
df["age"]= (df["age"] == 0).all(1)
```

But it's failed...anyone can help with this??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the data you have is, but try this.

```
import numpy as np
df['age'] = np.where(df['age']==0, 1, df['age'])
```

Comment: df["age"] = 2019 - df["Year"] 
df['age'] = np.where(df['age']==0, 1, df['age'])

Comment: df['age'] = np.where((2019 - df['Year'])==0,1,(2019 - df['Year'])). This one can work

Comment: If you want to calculate the age of 2019 in the age column, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Toy example,

**Input**

```
    year    model
0   2019    a
1   2018    b
2   2017    c
3   2019    d


df=pd.DataFrame({
    'year':[2019, 2018, 2017, 2019],
    'model':['a','b','c','d']
})
df['age'] = np.where((2019 - df.year)==0,1,(2019 - df.year))
df
```

**Output**

```
    year    model   age
0   2019    a       1
1   2018    b       1
2   2017    c       2
3   2019    d       1
```

Comment: df['age'] = np.where((2019 - df['Year'])==0,1,(2019 - df['Year'])) .This one can work